# Copying contents of list of files to another file using for loop separated by new line - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to copy contents of of a list of files into a single file. The content of each file is separated by a new line character. I tried the following

```
for file in os.listdir(files_path):
        path = os.path.join(files_path, file)
        with open(path) as f:
            with open(dest_file, "a") as f1:
                f1.write("\n")
                for line in f:
                    f1.write(line)
```

I expected this:

```
previous content of dest file

content of file 1

content of file 2

content of file 3
```

But got this:

```
previous content




content of file 1
content of file 2
content of file 3
```

This is totally bizarre for me :\

**EDIT : Now I just tried this and it makes me go mad.**

```
file1 = open("dest.txt",'a')

file1.write("hello")
file1.write("\n")
file1.write("hi")

file1.close()
```

The dest.txt file contains only this:

```
hello
hi
```

I opened the file in Notepad++ and enabled 'Show All Characters' and found this:
[image: Notepad++ snip]

**EDIT 2:** I had to write this `file1.write("\n")` twice to get the output as how I wanted. I guess my problem is solved now! Added answer to explain what happened.

Comment: Why is this surprising? `f1.write("\n")` is **outside** the `for` loop...

Comment: Are you sure it is a recursive code?

Comment: @jonsharpe - but its in the first for loop. There should be a new line between the contents of each file.

Comment: @ViChu - you should remove the word "recursive" from the title. This isn't recursive code.

Comment: I tested your code sample and it works as expected so you have to look somewhere else for the strange results. Maybe you are writing a different file than you think or there is an error that you catch and supress. Try deleting the dest file completely and see whether it writes again or whether you were looking at the wrong file all along.

Comment: Check the newlines in your dest_file and source files.  I ran your code on my machine and it worked as expected.  You'll only get the spaces between lines if your source files already end in newlines.

Comment: @NateAllen has a great point. If you have some empty files and some files that don't end with a newline, you'll get the result you show.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm sorry about the wrong title. I'm out of words as to what to use.

Comment: @tdelaney I edited the code with this - f1.write("--------------123123123-----------------") .. added this piece before f1.write("\n") . The 1st line gets written to the file but the new line is omitted.

Comment: @NateAllen yes , each file which is copied ends with a new line but does that mean it wont insert a new line when I write to it ??

Comment: I just tried the same snippet with a sample - 3 files and one dest file. file1.txt file2.txt and file3.txt. Each contains only a single line of text. dest.txt file is an empty file. Still my output was one new line followed by contents of the 3 files. Please someone help me out ! :( 
EDIT: when I ran the code again, the new line character is also omitted now and only the content follow the previous content.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the dest file contains content and does not end with a new line. The cursor will be at the end of the last line. **Here ( | ) is the cursor.**

```
previous content|
```

Now `f1.write("\n")` will bring the cursor to the next line like this:

```
previous content
|
```

Adding `f1.write("\n")` will now bring the cursor to the next line and the new contents will be written starting from that line.

```
previous content

|(new contents)
```

This produces the expected output.